# How do you compare number intervals, written as strings, in Python?

Tags: python, module, intervals

For this data file that I'm working off, I am given pairs of lists where each element represents an age interval, but they're written as strings. For example,

`List1 = ['0-9', '10-19', '20-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-']`

`List2 = ['0-19', '20-39', '40-']`

List1 is used as a template to represent the age intervals for the corresponding data:

`A1 = [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80]`

`B1 = [33, 20, 40, 76, 777, 844]`

So, for example, the second element of A1 means the value is 40 for the age interval '10-19', the fifth element of B1 means the value is 777 for the interval '40-49'.

It is possible, because of the matching time intervals in List1 with List2, to sum the elements in A1 and B1 so that they now represent the time interval of List2.

`A2 = [70, 110, 150]`

`B2 = [53, 116, 1621]`

So now, for example, the second element of A2 (previously A1) represents the value 110 for the age interval '20-39' and the first element of B2 (previously B2) represents 53 for the interval '0-19'.

The data for List1 has been rebinned to match List2's age intervals. This is possible because of the overlapping age intervals. This cannot be done for data representing the following two age intervals:

`List3 = ['0-14', '15-29', '30-44', '45-']`

`List4 = ['0-19', '20-39', '40-']`

Because of the format of the data, I don't know how I can check if two lists has overlapping age intervals, which allows for data to be rebinned to represent a new set of age intervals. If anyone could point to me a method or library available in python that is capable of making such a task possible, specifically dealing with number intervals represented as strings, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can separate `'0-9'` into `('0', '9')` by `'0-9'.split('-')`. It could be your starting point. But I don't get the checking rule of your situation. Can you explain details?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will attempt to explain the details a bit more clearly: Each list contains age intervals, as shown above. However, for each of the lists I presented, there is tied another list with data for the corresponding age intervals. Because the elements of List1 can be summed in such a way to represent Lists2's age intervals, the other set of data for List1 can also be summed to match List2's age intervals. List3 and List4 represents a case where it's not possible to rebin the other data of those lists.

Comment: "if List1's elements can be summed to represent List2." I don't understand what this means. What is the underlying logic here?

Comment: @BoseongChoi I have updated my question. If anyone is still not clear, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Please let me know if the question is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: @user9977 Got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort out all younger ages in one [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=set#sets) and all older ages in an other set. Then see if all older ages of the shorter list exists in older from the longer list and the same for younger.
This way it will match not only pairs but any combination of singels, pairs, triplets etc.

```
def can_represent(short_list, long_list):
    youngs_1 = {s.split('-')[0] for s in short_list}
    youngs_2 = {s.split('-')[0] for s in long_list}
    olds_1 = {s.split('-')[1] for s in short_list}
    olds_2 = {s.split('-')[1] for s in long_list}
    return not youngs_1 - youngs_2 and not olds_1 - olds_2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jolbas, I like this alternative approach

Comment: @user9977 This function returns true if there are other combinations of age ranges than pairs too. For example 0-9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-  matches 0-9, 10-39, 40-

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `split` method to go from `'0-9'` to `('0', '19')`.
Applying this method to all the pairs could look like:

```py
list1 = [s.split('-') for s in list1]
list2 = [s.split('-') for s in list2]
```

Now we need to iterate over `list1` to merge pairs two by two.
I used the `zip` function to do so.

```py
merge = [[pair[0][0], pair[1][1]] for pair in list(zip(list1,list1[1:]))[::2]]
```

We then only need to compare our new `merge` list to `list2`.

```py
merge == list2
```

Everything together:

```py
def foo(list1, list2):
    list1 = [s.split('-') for s in list1]
    list2 = [s.split('-') for s in list2]
    merge = [[pair[0][0], pair[1][1]] for pair in list(zip(list1,list1[1:]))[::2]]
    return merge == list2

print(foo(List1, List2)) # True
print(foo(List3, List4)) # False
```

Comment: don't need to convert to int. don't need to convert to tuples:  `list1 = [s.split('-') for s in list1] \\ list2 = [s.split('-') for s in list2] \\ merge = [[pair[0][0], pair[1][1] if pair[1][1] else ''] for pair in list(zip(list1,list1[1:]))[::2]] \\ return merge == list2`

Comment: Indeed ! I lost myself trying to sum up the pairs at some point in my research ... Thanks for pointing that out ! I've edited my answer

Comment: And then also possible to remove the if else in `merge = [[pair[0][0], pair[1][1]] for pair in list(zip(list1,list1[1:]))[::2]]`

Comment: Nice catch once again !